# Refer Android studio to custom GLIBC_2.14

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, glibc

I am trying to build Android app using `ionic cordova build android` on `CentOS`

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

System:

    Node : v8.9.4
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Linux 2.6

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

However it's failing with below error, trying to find `GLIBC_2.14`

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.581 secs
(node:2440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /code/tanmay/web/web/utrade/static/utrade/HybridApp/ionic/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/tanmay/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/tanmay/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt)
/home/tanmay/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/tanmay/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/lib64/libc++.so)
```

My Admin won't install 2.14 version since it could break system. I then manually installed the 2.14 verison as suggested at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5

However using `EXPORT_LD_LIBRARY` didn't work. Also can't create soft link due to permission issue.

Is there a way to make Android Studio refer to the manually installed GLIBC. Or degrade it, use previous version of build tools,  to make it to use GLIBC_2.12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)